Convertir saltos de linea \r\n en un Texto Plano con PHP
Como saben, ya busque bastante y no logro dar con lo que necesito.
Consideremos el siguiente comentario escrito en un <textarea>

Hola
SOes
Soy Yenn

En la base se guarda como
Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn

Pasarlo a HTML no es problema alguno, el comentario se ve muy bien, cambio los \r\n por <br> con str_replace('\r\n','</br>',$comment) y todo perfecto.
El problema viene que si quiero modificar el texto, en mi textarea aparece el texto puro de la DB así: Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn
Y necesito que de alguna manera, el texto plano del textarea se vea con los saltos de línea. Que he intentado? Lo siguiente y nada funciona
$comment = 'Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn'; // Esto viene de la DB
nl2br($comment);
str_replace("\r\n", '<br>', $comment);
str_replace('\r\n', '<br>', $comment);
str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br>', $comment);
<pre>str_replace("\r\n", '<br>', $comment)</pre>
trim(preg_replace('/\n+/', ' ', $comment));
strip_tags($comment);

NADA DE NADA me permite "emular" los enter o saltos de línea. Y ya no se me ocurre algo más.
Alguna idea?? 

Edito Rápidamente (que ya salgo de la oficina). Yo inserto los datos así:
Cada variable que viene de un form la sanitizo varias veces, así:
$stars = $dbm->escapeString($_POST['rating']);
$sanedStars = $helpers->sanitizeInt($stars);

$comment = $dbm->escapeString($_POST['comment']);
$sanedComment = trim($helpers->sanitizeString($comment));

Y tengo más, sanitizeURL, sanitizeMail... o sea intento que todo quede "limpio"
Esas funciones son estas
public function escapeString($str){
    try {
        $MySQLi = $this->mysqli;
        if (!$MySQLi) {
            throw new Exception('<br><b>Error escapeString Function</b>');
        }
        else{
            return $MySQLi->real_escape_string($str);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}

public function sanitizeEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}

public function validateEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

public function sanitizeString($string) {
    return filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

public function sanitizeInt($int) {
    return filter_var($int, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}

Una vez saneadas esas variables, las guardo en DB. Este es el caso del comentario en cuestión, así es como estoy guardando estos comentarios. Y recalco, el comentario en vista HTML (osea en un card) se ve genial, no tengo problemas, el problema es (o era) que en el input textarea no se miraban los "enters" sino que los caracteres "\r\n"

Para las entradas de los post, como traen "enters" y en otras ocasiones vienen formateados con colores, sabores, divs, párrafos, en fin, vienen "con formato", lo que hago es insertar la variable pura del formulario así;
$content = $_POST['contentPOST'];
Y luego hago los replaces y todo se ve perfecto.

Por qué reemplazar los saltos de línea no funciona? A lo mejor deberías jugar con javascript

Hola @Yenn, tené en cuenta que no es lo mismo 'Hola\r\nSOes' (entre comillas simples) que "Hola\r\nSOes" (entre comillas dobles). En el 1er caso los caracteres \r y \n son exactamente esos caracteres (\, r y n), en cambio en el 2do caso son secuencias de escape para caracteres especiales. Más info. ¿Como se ve realmente la cadena al imprimirla?

La verdad no me queda claro el problema

@Marcos ya había tomado en cuento lo de las comillas y no me ha salido. @ Mateo, JS es mi talón de Aquiles por le momento

una pregunta decente.. 3 respuestas.. ni un voto a favor en la pregunta... :facepalm...

@gbianchi yo ya voté a favor de la primer respuesta  porqué me regaña?

a vos no.. a los que escribieron esas respuestas.. que tu pregunta esta muy bien...ahi aclare el comentario jajaja

aaaaaa ok, porque yo incluso dije que daría por aceptada la respuesta hasta encontrar la respuesta ideal (en base a criterio técnico), aunque creo que la respuesta con JS será la definitiva

Entonces en la base de datos se guardan las barras invertidas o se guarda normalmente solo que estás viendo el salto de línea escapado?

@Mateo LITERAL, el texto que remarco en mi pregunta. Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn. Así, con esas barras, sin espacios, ni nada, tal cual, cada ENTER, lo convierte en \r\n

@Yenn y cual es el código que usas para guardarlo en la base de datos?

@Mateo para el caso importa? Lo digo porque con la respuesta en JS se hace perfecto. El código para guardarlo lo único que hago es (al igual que el contenido de una entrada) el texto va tal cual viene del form, sin escapar ni nada. Si gusta, puedo editar mi pregunta explicando bien, como inserto este tipo de texto y como inserto mis otras variables, pueda que eso me ayude muchísimo

@Yenn no realmente. Tienes 2 opciones: modificar la forma en que guardas el string en la base datos, o modificar el string que obtienes de la base de datos para que se muestre correctamente.

@Mateo pregunta editada... Me voy, le respondo mañana

En el caso de que la cadena tenga simplemente caracteres (es decir, ni saltos de línea \n, ni retornos de carro \r), entonces es necesario reemplazar dichos caracteres por las secuencias correspondientes.
Ejemplo:
<?php

$comment = 'Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn';
$comment = str_replace(['\r', '\n'], ["\r", "\n"], $comment);
echo '<textarea>'.$comment.'</textarea>';

?>

Resultado:

Demo

@Marcos lo que no me queda claro es eso de las comillas, yo no uso comillas en ningún lado, primero era un echo puro echo $comment; luego usé todas las formas de la pregunta inicial (incluso cambiando comillas, que ya lo había leído en otros lados). A mí, su forma no me funciona y para no responder de una vez, opte por escribir su código y nop, en el textarea se siguen viendo los \r\n. Será que tengo algo que no veo??? Porque con el JS si funciona perfecto

O sea, yo puse $comment = 'Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn'; como referencia. El texto de la DB es literal Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn. Y como ve en mi pregunta, si había tomado en cuenta el uso de comillas simples y dobles. Las comillas tienen su función y entiendo cual es, por eso el hecho que si a usted le resulta, puede que sea porque desde la primer variable ya va "formateando" el texto con comillas dobles, es eso o estoy como Adan en día de madres y sigo sin entenderle, lo siento

@Yenn, fijate si lo que dejo en mi respuesta te funciona. Si te llega a funcionar "el problema" (si es que es un problema) esta en cómo guardas los datos en la DB o en cómo los recuperas.

@Marcos voy a editar la pregunta para que vean los insert que hago. Deme un minuto

@Yenn, ¿te funcionó? Creo que deberías crear una nueva pregunta, para así obtener la respuesta que buscas a "¿por que se guardan los saltos línea como caracteres literales en mi DB?" PD: es por la combinación del escape de MySQL con el filter  deberías aplicarlos al revez.

@Marcos la verdad no creo que sea necesario, he entendido la base de lo que me han dicho y lo tomaré muy en cuneta. Las comillas han vuelto hacer de las suyas

@Yenn, me parece que realmente no has entendido. Por una lado, lo de las comillas era para demostrar que las cadenas son diferentes. Y por otro lado, ahora estas planteando otra pregunta, que nada tiene que ver con la actual, ya que ahora queres saber porque se guardan "mal" los datos. PD: Lo que todavía me queda la duda si te funcionó mi solución

@Marcos gracias, con solo la linea echo str_replace(['\r', '\n'], ["\r", "\n"], $comment) se solventa todo. Aprendí mucho y debo decir que las benditas comillas me la han vuelto hacer
Y no, ya se el royo de las comillas literales en la DB, igual el uso de las diferentes comillas: simples, dobles, invertidas. Es más, eso lo he reafirmado cuando uso JS, que JS tiene bien definido su uso.

@Yenn, quisiera que no dejes pasar el hecho de que estas saneando mal los datos, el orden no es el correcto, lo último que debes hacer (independientemente de si aplicas filtros) es escapar la cadena. Ideal seria que uses Sentencias preparadas

@Marcos le parece si pasamos al chat?? Yo uso sentencias preparadas. Lo que no me queda claro es lo de los filtros mal aplicados, lo espero en el chat general si gusta...

Continuemos el debate en el chat.

En PHP, simplemente reemplaza el salto de linea-retorno de carro por   si quieres texto plano y usa strip_tags() para eliminar los caracteres :
<?php
$comment = "Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn"; // Esto viene de la DB

$textConvertido = str_replace("\r\n", " ", $comment);


echo strip_tags($textConvertido );
?>

donde obtendrías simplemente el texto plano de la cadena que viene de la base de datos:
Hola SOes Soy Yenn

Pero si quieres emular los saltos de linea, puedes usar nl2br() que inserta saltos de línea HTML antes de todas las nuevas líneas en una cadena.
<?php

$comment = "Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn"; // Esto viene de la DB

$textConvertido = nl2br($comment);

echo strip_tags($textConvertido );

?>

En este caso obtendrías como salida:
Hola
SOes
Soy Yenn


Jorge, estaba probando su respuesta y lo hice tal cual usted lo ha hecho y no, en el textarea se siguen visualizando los \r\n justo como lo tenia al inicio. Por el momento la respuesta con JS sigue siendo la única que si hace lo de poner los saltos de linea en el textarea

@Yenn probaste la segunda solución que usa las funciones : nl2br() y strip_tags() ?

Ambas mister, créame que ya lo había hecho antes, antes de crear una pregunta (aunque sea boba) yo ya he dado vuelta y media por internet buscando, porque se que puede ser algo tan fácil que esta es penoso

Suponiendo que estás usando un textarea, reemplazas el salto de línea con un br usando una expresión regular.


let texto = "Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn"
    
const regex = /\\n|\\r\\n|\\n\\r|\\r/g;
texto = texto.replace(regex, '<br>');
    
document.getElementById('test').value = texto;
<textarea id="test" type="text" rows="3"></textarea>




En efecto funciona, y daré por aceptada la respuesta. Pero, esto se podría hacer con PHP puro?? Lo digo porque me imagino que debe ser algo similar y recalco: JS no es mi fuerte. (Incluso analicé algunos códigos JS pero no les logré entender)

Funciona pero la línea texto = texto.replace(regex, '<br>') no hace nada. Si prestan atención, el texto es el mismo después de aplicar el reemplazo. No será "Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn"? Por cierto, \n\r no se usa en ningún sistema operativo, solo \r, \n y \r\n; o CL, RF y CLRF si lo prefieren así.

@Mateo en efecto, he probado y quitando esa linea funciona perfecto. Pero ahora la duda es, porque mágicamente se hace el replace??? Mi lógica me decía que esa linea hace el replace entre las variables "texto" y "regex". Pero no

@Yenn simplemente el string "Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn" funciona. Porque "\r" y "\n" no se imprimen literalmente, sino que son secuencias de escape que corresponden a retorno de carro y nueva línea.

@Mateo pero entonces, si yo no uso comillas en PHP pero en el script JS si uso, en la linea let texto = "<?php echo $comment; ?>"; esas comillas hacen TODA la magia???

@Yenn no sé si sabes otros lenguajes, Python, Javascript, C#, C++, etc. En todos ellos no puedes poner un salto de línea u otros caracteres directamente en el literal de string. Bueno, en el literal, la secuencia "\n" representa un salto de línea. Entonces, sí, teniendo en cuenta que PHP literalmente reemplaza <?php echo $comment; ?> por Hola\r\nSOes\r\nSoy Yenn, las comillas del código Javascript están haciendo la magia.

@Yenn, sí, porque con PHP solo imprimis cadena con los caracteres literales, pero cuando JS evalúa el código, los interpreta como secuencias de escape. Ahora si con PHP imprimieras secuencias de escape en JS, el navegador al evaluarlo se rompería. Para evitarlo deberías usar tildes invertidas

@Marcos pregunta editada... Me voy, le respondo mañana, aunque creo que más o menos ya capté su idea...

Gracias javdromero, su respuesta es súper buena pero daré como aceptada la de @Marcos ya que he aprendido mucho y usando solo una linea de PHP echo str_replace(['\r', '\n'], ["\r", "\n"], $comment) puedo resolver el tema de las benditas comillas. Gracias mil

Coincido que esa respuesta es mejor y es justamente lo que necesitas en php
